# Undefined index with Session variables

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm having a problem with 3 Session variables, I have a file called *chat.php* this is:

```
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
protected $clients;
protected $data_clients;
protected $target = "xxxxx"; //conversation target number/JID

public function __construct() {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    $this->data_clients = new \SplObjectStorage;

    session_start();
    echo 'begin';
    $_SESSION["running"] = time();
    $_SESSION["inbound"] = array();
    $_SESSION["outbound"] = array();
    echo 'end';

    $this->send_message('hello');

    $this->Listen(true);

}



public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
    $conn->close();
}

public function Listen($initial){
   $band=false;

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 40000
    );

    $params=['initial'=>$initial, 'target'=>$this->target,'method'=>'prueba'];
    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'localhost/socket/src/myApp/script2.php',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));
    curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        $band=true;
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    if(!$band)
        $this->Listen(false);
}//fin Listen


public function send_message($mensaje){

    $band=false;
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    );

    $params=['method'=>'sendMessage','target'=>$this->target,'message'=>$mensaje];
    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'localhost/socket/src/myApp/ajax2.php',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


}//fin de enviar mensaje
}
```

So, I *$this->send_message('hello')* from the construct the function calls a script called ajax2, but then I'm having this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: outbound in C:\xampp\htdocs\socket\src\myApp\ajax2.php on line 16
envia
Notice: Undefined index: running in C:\xampp\htdocs\socket\src\myApp\socket2.php on line 15
```

The content of ajax2 is:

```
    <?php
session_start();

$method = $_POST["method"];

switch ($method) {
    case "sendMessage":
        $target = $_POST["target"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $outbound = $_SESSION["outbound"];
        $outbound[] = array("target" => $target, "body" => $message);
        $_SESSION["outbound"] = $outbound;
        break;
    case "pollMessages":
        $inbound = @$_SESSION["inbound"];
        $_SESSION["inbound"] = array();
        $profilepic = @$_SESSION["profilepic"];
        $ret = new JSONResponse();
        if ($profilepic != null && $profilepic != "") {
            $ret->profilepic = $profilepic;
        }
        $_SESSION["profilepic"] = "";
        if (count($inbound) > 0) {
            foreach ($inbound as $message) {
                $ret->messages[] = $message;
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($ret);
        break;
}
```

So, the problem is with the session variables, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I already made *session_start* even. If you see, I created them in the construct before use them in ajax2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

its not working cause you are trying to access session variables  $_SESSION["outbound"],$_SESSION["inbound"],$_SESSION["profilepic"] of a completely different session in ajax2.php

cause session created in chat.php by session_start(); is different to the session creted in ajax2.php by session_start(); cause your are accessing ajax2.php through CURL which create a new section in ajax2.php which will be different to session crated in chat.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an [explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/305455) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!